# Apply a formula to many rows without autofill and dragging

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula, =INDEX(B:B;MATCH(1;(D:D=I3)*(E:E=K3);0)), that searches for a value in column B that matches to the values in columns D and E, given these values in cells I3 and K3. But I have many values in columns I and K, so I want to apply these formula to them as well.

| **Database** | value |  | code1 | code2 |  |  |  | **Given** |  |  |  |  | **Desired Result** |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 |  | 123 | 1 |  |  |  | code1 | code2 | value |  |  | code1 | code2 | value |
|  | 1 |  | 122 | 2 |  |  |  | 123 | 1 | 1 |  |  | 123 | 1 | 1 |
|  | 2 |  | 124 | 2 |  |  |  | 122 | 2 |  |  |  | 122 | 2 | 1 |
|  | 3 |  | 125 | 2 |  |  |  | 124 | 2 |  |  |  | 124 | 2 | 2 |
|  | 4 |  | 126 | 3 |  |  |  | 125 | 2 |  |  |  | 125 | 2 | 3 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 126 | 3 |  |  |  | 126 | 3 | 4 |

I could use drag&down, but is there a way to apply this formula to an array given in columns I and K without using autofill?

Comment: Yes, but you need to improve your question to get a proper answer. Use markdown table to paste data as data, not as a screenshot and provide the expected result with given sample data. (Also it would be nice accepting an answer from previous asked and answered questions by clicking the `✓` left from the answer.

Comment: @P.b well, I couldn't do it with markdown, so I inserted a screenshot again, sorry. Are there any ways to solve it without drag&down?

Comment: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: By the way, your screenshot is showing different columns from the formula.

Comment: @P.b could you be able to see it now?

Comment: =BYROW(I2:J6,LAMBDA(x,FILTER(B:B,(D:D=CHOOSECOLS(x,1))*(E:E=CHOOSECOLS(x,2)))))

Comment: @Sherkh refer answers just posted.

Comment: @user11222393 your formula needs to be this as OP is using `Column I ` & `Column K` therefore -- `=BYROW(I2:K6,LAMBDA(x,FILTER(B:B,(D:D=CHOOSECOLS(x,1))*(E:E=CHOOSECOLS(x,3)))))`

Comment: You are right, took a look at OP's dataset, but didn't look at INDEX formula provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using <kbd>MAP( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>L2</kbd>

```
=MAP(I2:I6,K2:K6,LAMBDA(x,y,
    INDEX(B2:B6,XMATCH(1,(x=D2:D6)*(y=E2:E6)))))
```

---

Or, use <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> instead of <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> & <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd> or <kbd>XMATCH( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>L2</kbd>

```
=MAP(I2:I6,K2:K6,LAMBDA(a,b,
    XLOOKUP(1,(a=D2:D6)*(b=E2:E6),B2:B6)))
```

---

Another alternative which updates dynamically and automatically :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>L2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     p,MATCH(7^89,I:I),
     q,I2:INDEX(I:I,p),
     r,K2:INDEX(K:K,p),
     MAP(q,r,LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP(1,(x=D:D)*(y=E:E),B:B,""))))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Going back to one of the pictures that got removed during the editing process.

[image: Removed Picture]

Here's a ridiculously simple solution involving nothing more the than user interface.

1. Copy the formula in cell `L3` onto clipboard using Ctrl+C.
2. Use left-arrow to select cell `K3`, then Ctrl+Down to get to last cell used in column `K`, then right arrow to move back into column `L`. Now paste formula from clipboard into this last cell in column `L` using Ctr+V.
3. Use Ctrl+Up to get back to `L3`, and again copy the formula to the clipboard using Ctrl+C.
4. Finally, use Ctrl+Shift+Down to select the whole range in column `L` where formulas are required and then use Ctrl+V to copy the formula from the clipboard to every cell in the range.

If your problem is that dragging down is cumbersome because of the sheer number of rows involved then the above is a very old, tried and tested solution. No functions, no dynamic arrays, and less than half the keystrokes required to type the original formula into cell `L3`.